# Better way to dynamically call namespaced methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, net-http

I was curious when building a method to call an endpoint using the Net::HTTP library in rails. As the endpoint I was calling accepted the same body but with multiple request methods, I wanted to dynamically call Net::HTTP.

To do this, I used this concoction

```rb
req_method = Object.const_get "Net::HTTP::#{method.capitalize}"
```

But feel this is ugly and not elegant. Is there a more rails or just a cleaner way to call that method in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't just do something like this?
`Net::HTTP.public_send(method.capitalize)`

Comment: Nice. A neater alternative for sure. Had forgotten about ‘public_send’ 

Comment: Actually. I just tried this and it doesn't work. Unfortunately you get the error NoMethodError: undefined method `Post' for Net::HTTP:Class as we are actually trying to call the Post/Delete/Get classes which aren't methods of the HTTP class hence the :: namespace tetradot

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You don't need to use capitalize method: Net::HTTP.public_send(method), where method can be get, post, etc. Don't forget that this methods requires host and params